# The relationship between file and token of NFT is 1-n relationship?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, nft, erc-721

I'm a newbie on this field. Yesterday I accidently mint nft several times with the same file on IPFS, and it actually create several tokens that link to the same file. The spirit of NFT is non-fungible, indivisible and it comes with ownership, but in this case, we can use one original file then list up as many as tokens we want. And when we sell these tokens, many people own the same original file. It doesn't seem right, it goes against the spirit of nft, right?
This is my technical mistake or something I that I'm missing of the whole picture of NFT. Could you give your advice?

Answer (score 0):

Yes as you say this is a sort of a technical mistake. Technically nothing stops you from creating multiple NFTs pointing to the same metadata, NFTs that contain unauthorized copies of some copyright content etc.